# RegEx for css class name

Tags: css

I want to have a class `cX` where x is a number between 0 and 100. I could add `c0` to `c100` to my css. But well, I'd like to avoid that.

I know there are ways to match element attributes like `h2[rel="external"]`. But is it also possible to match class names? Would it also possible to use the matched value within the rule?

Example

```
.c[x] { height: x%; }
```

Comment: What should happen if say there is an element with class c101?

Comment: @Harry ideally the rule would ignore it. But I could live without the restriction

Comment: @CBroe how is this a duplicate? I want to know how to reuse the matched value as well. I don't see that in the question or in any answer.

Comment: You are looking for elements whose class name match a specific pattern and so that answer should be the solution. As for **matched value**, no you **can't do that with CSS**.

Comment: @Harry when I match `24` i want to use it and set `height: 24px`

Comment: Why not use SASS to generate all the rules you want?

Comment: well then, JavaScript manipulation or server-side script to output inline CSS.. I don't think a pure CSS solution exists

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that part too; voted to re-open. Agree with @Aziz, a CSS preprocessor like SASS or LESS is what you should use to achieve this. (Another option would be client-side creation of the necessary stylesheet rules via JavaScript.)

Comment: Unless you’re planning to use this in excess (thousands of classes, different names) or to set dozens of different properties each time, I don’t think filesize should be an issue. Especially if you GZIP it before sending to the client.

Comment: @Aziz inline css wouldn't change the file size in the end, I care more about the transferred filesize than the stylesheet filesize. CBroe: yeah may be micro-optimization but I was curios if it's possible, since it would be neat.

Comment: _“I care more about the transferred filesize than the stylesheet filesize”_ – again, I think GZIP should compress that quite well, especially since it will contain so much repetition.

Comment: the 100 CSS rules would generate a 2kb file, very very small and could be 1kb GZIPPED

Comment: @Brettetete: I've reopened it but as I said earlier you can't reuse the value inside the ruleset. There is no other pure CSS solution for it.

Comment: I found it, it's CSS `attr` function, see my answer - however it is not supported ATM so you'll have to resort to the other methods

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT - CSS `attr`

After a bit of research, I found that there is a CSS function called `attr` which is exactly what you are looking for, however, its support is currently limited to the CSS `content` property and not others, however, it is interesting to keep an eye on it, I reckon it will be the solution of the future

From [Moz MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr):

> The attr() CSS function is used to retrieve the value of an attribute
>   of the selected element and use it in the style sheet. It can be used
>   on pseudo-elements too and, in this case, the value of the attribute
>   on the pseudo-element's originated element is returned.

Your code would probably look like this:

```
.c { height: attr(data-height %, 0); }
```

HTML

```
<div class="c" data-height="1"></div>
...
```

This will get the height from the element's data attribute and sets it with the `%` percentage unit and falls back to `0` if `data-height` is not found.

---

Current supported methods:

From the [W3 Docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings):

> **6.3.2. Substring matching attribute selectors**
>
> Three additional attribute selectors are provided for matching
>   substrings in the value of an attribute:
>
> `[att^=val]`
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value
>   begins with the prefix "val". If "val" is the empty string then the
>   selector does not represent anything.
>
> `[att$=val]`
>
> Represents an element
>   with the att attribute whose value ends with the suffix "val". If
>   "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent
>   anything.
>
> `[att*=val]`
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute
>   whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If
>   "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent
>   anything. Attribute values must be CSS **identifiers or strings**. [CSS21]
>   The case-sensitivity of attribute names in selectors depends on the
>   document language.

As discussed in the comments, there is no pure CSS solution at the moment, you could try one of the following approaches:

### SASS

```
@for $i from 1 through 100 {
    $height: percentage($i/100);
   .c#{$i} {height: $height;}
}
```

Output:

```
.c1 {height: 1%;}

.c2 {height: 2%;}

.c3 {height: 3%;}

...
```

---

### LESS

```
.c-gen(@index) when (@index > 0){
  .c@{index}{
    height: @index * 1%;
  }
  .c-gen(@index - 1);
}
.c-gen(100);
```

[LESS code](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.c-gen(%40index)%20when%20(%40index%20%3E%200)%7B%5Cn%20%20.c%40%7Bindex%7D%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20height%3A%20%40index%20*%201%25%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20.c-gen(%40index%20-%201)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn.c-gen(100)%3B%22%7D) by [Harry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2606013/harry)

---

### Server Side

You could make your server side script output inline CSS for each item

PHP Example:

```
<?php 
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo "<span height='".$i."%'>".$i."</span>";
} 
?>
```

Output

```
<span height="1%">1</span>
...
```

---

### jQuery

```
var i = 0;
$('.c').each(function() {
  i++;
  $(this).attr('height', i + '%');
  //console.log(i); //debug
});
```

Comment: [Here](http://lesscss.org/less-preview/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22.c-gen(%40index)%20when%20(%40index%20%3E%200)%7B%5Cn%20%20.c%40%7Bindex%7D%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20height%3A%20%40index%20*%201%25%3B%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20.c-gen(%40index%20-%201)%3B%5Cn%7D%5Cn.c-gen(100)%3B%22%7D) is a version using Less. Feel free to add it to your answer as I don't think there is much point in adding another one.